# Clojure confusion - behavior of map, doseq in a multiprocess environment

Tags: clojure

In trying to replicate some websockets examples I've run into some behavior I don't understand and can't seem to find documentation for. Simplified, here's an example I'm running in lein that's supposed to run a function for every element in a shared map once per second:

```
(def clients (atom {"a" "b" "c" "d" }))

(def ticker-agent (agent nil))

(defn execute [a]
        (println "execute")
        (let [ keys (keys @clients) ]   
            (println "keys= " keys )
            (doseq [ x keys ] (println x)))
            ;(map   (fn [k]  (println k)) keys)) ;; replace doseq with this?

        (Thread/sleep  1000)
        (send *agent* execute))


(defn -main [& args]
    (send ticker-agent execute)
 )
```

If I run this with map I get

```
execute
keys=  (a c)
execute
keys=  (a c)
...
```

First confusing issue: I understand that I'm likely using map incorrectly because there's no return value, but does that mean the inner println is optimized away? Especially given that if I run this in a repl:

```
(map #(println %) '(1 2 3))
```

it works fine?

Second question - if I run this with **doseq** instead of **map** I can run into conditions where the execution  agent stops (which I'd append here, but am having difficulty isolating/recreating). Clearly there's something I"m missing possibly relating to locking on the maps keyset? I was able to do this even moving the shared map out of an atom. Is there default syncrhonization on the clojure map?

Comment: @Charles, thanks for the responses - when I use the commented out map line, it's not running the function inside the map - i.e. not printing out the keys . The output reported is from the line about '(println "keys= " keys )'

Comment: Right -- maps are lazy, so their results aren't calculated unless you would use them. That's why doseq is the right tool for the job here. Nothing at all to do with locking/concurrency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map` is lazy. This means that it does not calculate any result until the result is accessed from the data structure it reteruns. This means that it will not run anything if its result is not used.

When you use `map` from the repl the print stage of the repl accesses the data, which causes any side effects in your mapped function to be invoked. Inside a function, if the return value is not investigated, any side effects in the mapping function will not occur.

You can use `doall` to force full evaluation of a lazy sequence. You can use `dorun` if you don't need the result value but want to ensure all side effects are invoked. Also you can use `mapv` which is not lazy (because vectors are never lazy), and gives you an associative data structure, which is often useful (better random access performance, optimized for appending rather than prepending).

Edit: Regarding the second part of your question (moving this here from a comment).

No, there is nothing about `doseq` that would hang your execution, try checking the [agent-error](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/agent-error) status of your agent to see if there is some exception, because agents stop executing and stop accepting new tasks by default if they hit an error condition. You can also use [set-error-model](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/set-error-mode!) and [set-error-handler!](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/set-error-handler!) to customize the agent's error handling behavior.

Comment: THanks, this is quite helpful. As to the second question , are there any conditions under which you could hang the execution with doseq?